# string conversion of floating point value

Tags: python, python-2.7

Reading about [floating point arithmetic in python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), I was trying some examples. To explain myself why `print 0.1+0.2` doesn't give `0.30000000000000004`, [from the docs on print statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print), I read that:

> print evaluates each expression in turn and writes the resulting
>   object to standard output (see below). If an object is not a string,
>   it is first converted to a string using the rules for string
>   conversions. The (resulting or original) string is then written.

Why does string conversion and hence the print statement too, rounds `0.30000000000000004` to `0.3`? Does this not make it difficult to know what floating point values my program is using, or how to know it?

Example:

```
In [17]: 0.1 + 0.2
Out[17]: 0.30000000000000004
In [18]: print 0.1 + 0.2
         0.3
In [20]: str(0.1 + 0.2)
Out[20]: '0.3'
```

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't reach that page myself